# Nodejs Repeat every system hour

Tags: node.js

I am using moment (for current time) and waitjs (repeat) modules.
If i write the codes as the below:

```
repeat(86400000, function() {  //DASHBOARD 
});
```

This function repeat every 1 hour. But it has counted since the program started. 
I want to work with system time. For example; when the system time 1:00:00 (A.M.) the function will be work. And continues every hour.
How can i do this?

**THANKS!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Moment.js and waitjs you would do something like this:

```
// Wait until end of hour
wait(moment().endOf('hour') - moment(), function() {
    // Start executing repeat function
    repeat(86400000, function() {  //DASHBOARD 
    });
});
```

Check out [Moment.js endOf](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/)

Comment: it passed the first minute (i tried with minutes to see the true work). Ex: current : 13:55:23 -- it works 13:57:00 passed the 56:00

Answer (score 1):

On program startup you can get the time until the next full hour, so for example:

- If the program starts at 1:20AM
- Time until the next full hour would be forty minutes.

Use this time to delay the execution of the first function call, this call be done with setTimemout (http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html). Following the example you would set a delay of forty minutes, and then the function would execute at 2:00AM.

You can then in this executed function, setup your repeat function to repeat every full hour.

Comment: good solution but i want to use moment and waitjs so cgross' answer is better for me. thanks for reply.